# добавление словарей в список

Tags: python, list, словари, for, dict

```
students = [
{'name':'Oliver', 'age':67, 'course':'python', 'gender':'Male'},
{'name':'Vlad', 'age':32, 'course':'python', 'gender':'Male'}
]
```

Имеется такой список, нужно через цикл добавить в этот список примерно такие же значения.
я пытался таким образом решить:

```
for q in range(10): 
    students.append(
    {'name':'Jannat', 'age':89, 'course':'python', 'gender':'Female'},
    {'name':'Chris', 'age':51, 'course':'python', 'gender':'Female'}, ......)
print(students)
```

нужно получить:

```
students = [ 

{'name':'Oliver', 'age':67, 'course':'python', 'gender':'Male'},
{'name':'Vlad', 'age':32, 'course':'python', 'gender':'Male'},
{'name':'Jannat', 'age':89, 'course':'python', 'gender':'Female'},
{'name':'Chris', 'age':51, 'course':'python', 'gender':'Female'},

]
```

Comment: Приведите в вопросе результат, который вы хотите получить и собственную попытку решения

Comment: воспользуйтесь кнопкой ["править"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1273999/edit) под вопросом, чтобы отредактировать вопрос)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через `append` можно добавлять в список одиночные объекты (в данном случае это словари):

```
students.append(
{'name':'Jannat', 'age':89, 'course':'python', 'gender':'Female'}
)
```

Если хотите добавлять в список сразу несколько объектов (словарей в вашем случае), используйте метод `extend` и передавайте ему коллекцию (например, список) ваших объектов (словарей):

```
students.extend([
{'name':'Jannat', 'age':89, 'course':'python', 'gender':'Female'},
{'name':'Oliver', 'age':67, 'course':'python', 'gender':'Male'}
])
```